# Force repaint of wxPython Window, wxmpl plot

Tags: python, wxpython, wxmpl

I'm having problems getting my wxPython window to refresh.  It's currently plotting a graph using wxmpl which can be zoomed, panned, etc.  On occasion the user may plot a large amount of data and zoom in on a small portion, which can cause it to 'freeze up'.  By that I mean the plot itself is not updated, and the axis labels are drawn on top of each other.  It is modifying the plot, just not displaying the updated info correctly.  If you resize the window the plot is redrawn correctly.

I've spend an inordinate amount of time digging through source code and documentation for wx, wxmpl, and matplotlib... The best solution I've come up with is resizing the window to force a repaint (thus displaying the updated plot correctly).

```
# All of these fail - displays the same, incorrect plot
# (view is a wxmpl.PlotPanel object, which inherits from wx.Window among other things)
view.Refresh()
view.Update()
view.draw()

# This works, but is clearly less than ideal
view.SetSize((view.GetSize().width, view.GetSize().height+1))
view.SetSize((view.GetSize().width, view.GetSize().height-1))
```

There's got to be a better way - what I really want to know is what wx.Window.SetSize does to redraw the window, and just call that instead.  Or, is there another method that I missed somewhere?

Comment: Where exactly are you making these calls? Refresh command will not work if you are calling it at the wrong place.
I am a regular user of wxpython and I do encounter somewhat similar problems like you, but placing the widget.Refresh() call at the right place always works for me.

Comment: I'm calling it immediately after resetting the limits to the plot in the window, which is on a left button up event.

Comment: I am using multiple wx.Panels that I Hide()/Show() with exact same results. Only thing that refreshes them correctly is resizing the window. Was using window.Layout(), it works for the first switch but not the rest.

Answer (score 3):

The panel.Layout() command is a great option because it is exactly the same method that is called when you resize your window. I also had trouble with the refresh and update methods. Layout seems to work when those two fail.

Comment: +400 on this comment.  This helps a lot for matplotlib figures.  Now they show when I want!

Comment: This is wonderful. I've been having the same issue and `panel.Layout()` solved it. I have no idea why matplotlib doesn't like Refresh() or Update(). Ah well... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you can't place it anywhere else, you could try

```
wx.Yield()
```

instead of `Refresh` or `Update`.

Comment: That didn't work either - same deal as with `Refresh` and `Update` :(

Answer (score 1):

I would also try Show(False) and then Show(True) on the PlotPanel.

Answer (score 0):

In a computational expensive application, where you are expecting something to be calculated for over 0.1 sec and probably have some user input it is not recommended usually to make those intense drawing in the GUI thread.

Not aware of your specific situation, but general approach if that you move all time consuming tasks (be it computation, image adjustment (e.g. scaling)) to the non GUI thread. Just a normal Python thread is fine, and once you have an long part complete, you refresh your GUI. During computation of course it would be a user friendly to display some sort of "waiting" sign. Also disable other controls, so bored user will not be able to change anything midway to your computation.

I was stuck with that issue since my early days with Java and later with Python, mostly in connection to network operations (which NEVER should be in GUI thread).

In case it is image adjusment (or graphics generation), which takes much time, background thread can prepare image in wxMemoryDC and then wxDC::Blit it to the window of your choice. I am not aware if this can be done with your component wxmpl.PlotPanel, so you will have to research this.